# How to determine MySQL max_allowed_packet size required

Tags: mysql

I have a Classic ASP script that retrieves data from an external XML feed, and stores the processed data in my MySQL database either using INSERT or UPDATE statements.  For small requests this is working fine.

However, because the data is so large in certain instances, I'm frequently getting the message in my log file "MySQL server has gone away".

I read on numerous sites that this could be caused by the MySQL server disconnecting my connection because the Packet size is too large.

Therefore I increased the MySQL server setting max_allowed_packet to 128M.  However I'm still getting this problem.

Is there any way to determine and capture what the max_allowed_packet size of this data update is, that is causing this problem ?

Comment: Did you restart the MySQL service. Also execute "show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';"

Comment: Yes I restarted the MySQL Service and it when running the command it shows max_allowed_packet as 134216704 bytes which is 127.999 mb